# Setting an SQL count as a variable in java

Tags: java, sql, database

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM `hs` WHERE `username` ='"+c.playerName+"' LIMIT 1");
int rows = 0;

try
{
    rs.last();
    rows = rs.getRow();
    rs.beforeFirst();
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}

if(rows > 0)
{
    query("UPDATE `hs` SET `overall_lvl` = '"+overallLVL+"',`overall_xp` = '"+overallXP+"',`attack_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[0]+"',`attack_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[0]+"',`defence_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[1]+"',`defence_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[1]+"',`strength_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[2]+"',`strength_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[2]+"',`ranged_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[3]+"',`ranged_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[3]+"',`prayer_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[4]+"',`prayer_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[4]+"',`magic_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[5]+"',`magic_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[5]+"',`cooking_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[6]+"',`cooking_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[6]+"',`woodcutting_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[7]+"',`woodcutting_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[7]+"',`fletching_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[8]+"',`fletching_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[8]+"',`fishing_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[9]+"',`fishing_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[9]+"',`firemaking_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[10]+"',`firemaking_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[10]+"',`crafting_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[11]+"',`crafting_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[11]+"',`smithing_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[12]+"',`smithing_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[12]+"',`mining_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[13]+"',`mining_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[13]+"',`herblore_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[14]+"',`herblore_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[14]+"',`agility_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[15]+"',`agility_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[15]+"',`thieving_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[16]+"',`thieving_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[16]+"',`slayer_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[17]+"',`slayer_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[17]+"',`farming_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[18]+"',`farming_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[18]+"',`runecrafting_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[19]+"',`runecrafting_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[19]+"',WHERE `username` = '"+c.playerName+"'");
}
else
{
    query("INSERT INTO `hs` SET `username` = '"+c.playerName+"', `overall_lvl` = '"+overallLVL+"',`overall_xp` = '"+overallXP+"',`attack_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[0]+"',`attack_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[0]+"',`defence_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[1]+"',`defence_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[1]+"',`strength_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[2]+"',`strength_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[2]+"',`ranged_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[3]+"',`ranged_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[3]+"',`prayer_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[4]+"',`prayer_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[4]+"',`magic_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[5]+"',`magic_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[5]+"',`cooking_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[6]+"',`cooking_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[6]+"',`woodcutting_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[7]+"',`woodcutting_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[7]+"',`fletching_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[8]+"',`fletching_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[8]+"',`fishing_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[9]+"',`fishing_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[9]+"',`firemaking_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[10]+"',`firemaking_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[10]+"',`crafting_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[11]+"',`crafting_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[11]+"',`smithing_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[12]+"',`smithing_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[12]+"',`mining_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[13]+"',`mining_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[13]+"',`herblore_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[14]+"',`herblore_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[14]+"',`agility_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[15]+"',`agility_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[15]+"',`thieving_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[16]+"',`thieving_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[16]+"',`slayer_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[17]+"',`slayer_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[17]+"',`farming_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[18]+"',`farming_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[18]+"',`runecrafting_lvl` = '"+c.playerLevel[19]+"',`runecrafting_xp` = '"+c.playerXP[19]+"'");

}
```

When I run this, it only will execute the insert and on second run it won't execute again. I believe it's to do with the rows not correctly turning into an int. What can I do to set this up correctly?

Comment: Please, learn how to use parameters, do not use string concatenation because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be:

```
int rows; // No need to initialize
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*)" +
                                                     " FROM `hs`" +
                                                    " WHERE `username` = ?")) { // No need for LIMIT 1
    stmt.setString(1, c.playerName); // This prevents syntax errors and SQL Injection issues
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        rs.next(); // SELECT count(*) always returns exactly 1 row
        rows = rs.getInt(1); // Get value of first column
    }
}
```

Please(!) use `PreparedStatement` for your INSERT and UPDATE statements too.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you do the `last()` and `getRow()` there - the "default" way of getting the one and only result from your count(*) would be like this:

```
int rows = 0;
try {
  //Check if there is a row - the if you could leave out in this case.
  if(rs.next()) {
    //Get the int as position 1 in the result - that's your count(*)
    rows = rs.getInt(1);
  }
```

Please also consider **closing** your `Statement`s and `ResultSet`s. You create resource leaks otherwise.

Also you should check into `PreparedStatement` and it's use in order to prevent SQL Injection in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**A select count query returns always 1 row**.

You need to get the value of the count and test if that value is > 0 or not.

The correct code should be similar to the following:

```
long rows = 0;
try {
   if (rs.next()) {
       rows = rs.getLong(1);
   }
   if (rows > 0) {
       // Query for update
   } else {
       // Query for insert
   }
   ....
```

**Additional tip:** don't use a `Statement`. Use instead a `PreparedStament`, it solve problems related to sql injection and are simpler to read from a programmer point of view

Comment: So i suppose the use of `getRow()` is just an mistake here?

Comment: Yes sorry, it should be a long, with the related method getLong(1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to change query to

```
SELECT count(*) cnt FROM
```

and then use

```
rs.getInt("cnt"); // do something
```